# Zeroes of $x\cdot \cos(x)-1$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, trigonometry

Is there some way to explicitly compute the solutions of $\cfrac 1y=\cos(y)$?

Background to this question: Question 3a) from [last year’s Bavarian state exam](https://staatsexamen.didmath.ewf.uni-erlangen.de/Examina/Mathematik_Examen/Analysis/H20III.pdf) yields after some computations to the problem of solving precisely that equation.

$$f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R \\ f(x,y)=-x^2 +y\space\text{exp}(x^2)-\sin(y)$$

> 3a. Determine all critical points of the function $f$

Comment: Hello :) I don't think there is an explicite way to do this, but how do you get there after some computations? Maybe there is a mistake.

Comment: The exam problem is to compute the critical,points of $-x^2+ye^{x^2}-sin(y)$. The partial derivatives are $-2x+ye^{x^2}2x$ and $e^{x^2}-cos(y)$. Setting them zero yields solutions either $(0,2k\pi)$ or $y=e^{-x^2}$ whence $1/y-cos(y)=0$. So it seems one cannot avoid solving this equation.

Comment: The context of the problem is a bit more restrictive than you've indicated: The condition for critical points, aside from $x=y=0$, is that $e^{x^2}=1/y=\cos y$. But $e^{x^2}\geq 1$ for any real $x$, so one would need to take $\cos(y)=1$ regardless. This rules out the possibility of any additional critical points.

Comment: Oh I see. (You mean cos(y)=1, but I understand anyway.) That’s really a bit tricky.

Comment: Why didn't you tell that there are bounds for $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: There are no bounds, they just come from the properties of the cosine and the exp-function.